# External wcf (Soap/rest) datasource to external content type

Tags: list, sharepoint-designer, external-content-type, wcf

I'm looking for a way to use an external datasource (WCF SOAP or REST) and include the results in a list. Using the External Content Type directly for a WCF service does not work, as I get a XML error (cannot create).

I can create an external datasource with Visual Studio (WCF soap webpart soap), which actually shows in Sharepoint (list with datasources). However, I see no way to link this to the list of External Content Types or direcly to a list in a webpart.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to configure the external content source, the simplest approach is to use SharePoint Designer  and externa list, this blog post from the Lightening Tools guys will help: http://www.lightningtools.com/blog/archive/2010/01/05/spd-external-content-type-from-wcf.aspx

Comment: if a response answers your query it's good practice to mark the response as an answer help our others with the same question.